# angular-cli with webpack and ng2-bootstrap-grid

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, ng2-bootstrap

I am converting my angular4 project to be intialized by angular-cli with webpack. In the original one, I am using [ng2-bootstrap-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap-grid) package as grid solution.

Now, when I start application by `webpack-dev-server --port=3000` I get this error:

`ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol NgModule in /home/tepo/IdeaProjects/vedica-gui/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-grid/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module.d.ts, resolving symbol NgModule in /home/tepo/IdeaProjects/vedica-gui/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-grid/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata.d.ts, resolving symbol NgModule in /home/tepo/IdeaProjects/vedica-gui/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-grid/node_modules/@angular/core/src/core.d.ts, resolving symbol NgModule in /home/tepo/IdeaProjects/vedica-gui/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-grid/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts, resolving symbol BootstrapGridModule in /home/tepo/IdeaProjects/vedica-gui/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-grid/index.ts, resolving symbol BootstrapGridModule in /home/tepo/IdeaProjects/vedica-gui/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap-grid/index.ts`

Can you advice how to deal with this? Didn't find anything on the web.
Thanks

EDIT: 
adding package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vedica-gui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=3000",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/filesaver": "0.0.30",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-http-file-upload": "^1.0.6",
    "angular2-logger": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap-grid": "^0.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.80",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.5",
    "webpack": "~2.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Double check if your pakage.json has ^ symbols for the references and your server is using one version above as describe in angular-cli github issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4647

Comment: I'm not really sure I know what you mean so I edited my question and added package.json. Can you see some inconsistency there?

Comment: I would suggest to you to change every  ^ to ˜ and clear you node path , "npm i "  and finally  "npm run start"

Comment: did not help, unfortunatelly